# XML file not loading

Tags: php, xml

I'm quite new in PHP and I'm trying to read from a response of a webservice like this one:
http://voip.letscall.pt/VSServices/sendsms.ashx?login=123456&pass=3663&from=john&to=peter&text=hello

but so far I haven't had success reading the responses that it gets. Here it is what I got so far

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");

    $url = 'http://voip.letscall.pt/VSServices/sendsms.ashx?login=123456&pass=3663&from=john&to=peter&text=hello';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    echo $xml;

?>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: put in some debugging. do a file_get_contents() to capture the url's response, and dump that out. do you get xml? then stuff that xml through a validator, make sure it's not corrupted/invalid, etc... Never assume that a remote resource is working properly. always check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error reporting tells me that there is a problem with the encoding between what you are presenting and your response:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8");
```

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://voip.letscall.pt/VSServices/sendsms.ashx?login=123456&pass=3663&from=john&to=peter&text=hello:1: parser error : Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="***utf-16***"?>
<response>
  <sms_response_code>400</sms_response_code>
  <sms_response_text>Authorization failed.</sms_response_text>
  <sms_response_destination />
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try via string instead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: won't change anything. f_g_c will use the EXACT same mechanisms that s_l_s would anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The source XML is not well-formed. The XML prologue says this xml file is utf-16, so this is how it is parsing the file. But the file is *not* utf-16 encoded, it is utf-8 encoded.

Tell the source to fix their xml. If they won't do that, then you have to change the XML before you parse it, which is error-prone and *icky*. E.g.:

```
$xml = preg_replace(
          '/^(<\?[xX][mM][lL]\s+[^\?\>]+encoding\s*=\s*([\'"]))utf-16\2/u',
          '\1utf-8\2', file_get_contents($url));
```